# error message on mounting sparsebundle

Tags: macos, time-machine

i have a new mac and I want to retrieve some files from the backup of my previous one.

I have a disk mounted on a third Mac which is being used for Timemachine on both the new and old machine.  In Finder I can navigate to the disk and see the sparse bundles for all the machines that have used the disk for backup.  When I try and open the sparsebundle for the mac  want to retrieve files from I get a popup:
[image: error popup]

Any ideas on how to find out what the real problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Doh!  I figured it out -- The disk was still mounted on the original machine - once I eject it I was able to mount it on the new one.

Hopefully this might help someone in the future.